# How do I download and install an application from github?

Tags: software-installation, github

Im trying to get an app from github and install it on Ubuntu.

Usually in windows I just download an exe or msi file and 2x click it.
But in Ubuntu its either using a PPA or a deb file or from github.

I tried googling some guides regarding github it & the closest to the concern is [here](http://lifehacker.com/5983680/how-the-heck-do-i-use-github). I tried following the guide but got stuck on step 2. The guide wants me to setup a github account.

I am trying to get this github app ([Pesobit: PoS-based cryptocurrency](https://github.com/pesobitph/pesobit-source)).

Please guide me.

Comment: Which app? Can you kindly include more information on how you were trying to install it, which steps failed, the errors you got, etc

Comment: @Parto The link provided by OP is to setup a github account and that process is causing him/her confusion. You don't need to setup an account to download.

Comment: im trying to install this app at github:  https://github.com/pesobitph/pesobit-source

Answer (score 3):

1. That Git repository contains an [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/pesobitph/pesobit-source/blob/master/INSTALL) file, which is a common place for building and installation instructions. It reads:

   > See `doc/readme-qt.rst` for instructions on building Pesobit QT,
   >   the intended-for-end-users, nice-graphical-interface, reference
   >   implementation of Pesobit.
2. In [`doc/readme-qt.rst`](https://github.com/pesobitph/pesobit-source/blob/master/doc/readme-qt.rst) we can find installation instructions “for Debian and Ubuntu”:

   > First, make sure that the required packages for Qt5 development of your distribution are installed, for Debian and Ubuntu these are:
   >
   > ```
   > apt-get install qt5-default qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev libssl-dev libdb++-dev
   > ```
   >
   > then execute the following:
   >
   > ```
   > qmake
   > make
   > ```
   >
   > Alternatively, install Qt Creator and open the `pesobit-qt.pro` file.
   >
   > An executable named `pesobit-qt` will be built.

   You can also find a description of some useful build options in that file.

Comment: which is a common place for building --> what does building means in ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. The installation instructions for Ubuntu are cited in section 2 of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted link are instructions for setting up a Github account. You don't need to do that in order to download an application from Github.

Let's say I want to install this Github application: (https://github.com/elmystico/EnhanceIO) that uses a small SSD to accelerate a large HDD. I click the <kbd>Download</kbd> button on the page and download the Zip file.

You didn't say which application you were trying to download from Github so I couldn't use it in this answer.

After downloading your application from Github, you might want to post a new question on how to unzip the compressed file. Then you might want to post another new question on how to compile it (if necessary).

Comment: Why don't you `git clone` the repo instead?

Comment: @edwinksl because I'm not that advanced yet :( I'm still learning at kernel, grub, boot, udev, systemd, xorg and bash levels.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you've got it backwards then. Learn git before most of those.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix,yes,you nailed it in the head,what is next after pressing the green button (clone or download)

Comment: I used the download option but as the other gentleman said you should clone it. But I don't know how yet :(

Comment: @edwinksl, please guide us on how to clone

Comment: I don't want to bother ed with my homework. But I'm on my phone for 10 hours so can't research it.

Comment: how come am not recieving email notice regarding replies here? tsk i already tick the every 3hrs notice,but still nothing

Comment: Probably because I don't use @ user name in my comments which disappear when I use them on my phone.

Comment: @obo In my experience it can take over 24 hours to be notified via email. I would assume that the assumption is that you'll check here and there is no point in flooding your email with unneeded, out of date reminders. Note that this is an assumption on my part.

Comment: Taanks Elder. I'm working on Fanatic 100 days straight AU so obviously no need of email :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You might find this useful: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-git-and-github-on-ubuntu-14.04/

Comment: Thanks Elder. I've favorites this question and will review your link when I'm back on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Github is not a plug-and-play "app store" type of thing where you download compiled apps. Rather, it hosts source code that is used to build software--it is a place for app developers to publicly host their code, not the executable software. Those developers will usually package completed, stable versions of their software somewhere else for people like you to download it without having to learn how to compile things manually.

I did some quick web searching and could not find a way to actually download pre-compiled versions of this Pesobit software, so it appears to be a bleeding-edge development and your only option may be to learn how to compile the software yourself. Note that this would apply to Windows or MacOS too, if you used either of those operating system. The project's Github page should have a basic introduction on how to compile that particular piece of software, and the file repo should have a README file that you can read to get a sense of what to do.